# GStreamer define port used for outgoing traffic (rtsp)

Tags: rtsp, gstreamer

I try to get some custom rtsp software running that has an annoying quirk. It cannot negotiate the port on which it will send the video. It will always send the video to the port from which the request came. Here is a quick example:

Lets assume gstreamer uses port 51000 on the local machine to connect to port 8054 on the RTSP server. The RTSP server will then try to send the video to the machine gstreamer is running on to the port that gstreamer used locally to connect to the RTSP server in the first place.

The usual behavior that I know is that a port is negotiated and that will be used to stream the video.

Since I cannot use ports >50,000 on the machine gstreamer is running on I am looking for a way to make gstreamer use a local port of my choice to connect to the rtsp server.

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean. What is "Video Viewer" anyway? Does it allow you to set the port or port range it would use as the source port? If the server doesn't reply to the source port the viewer used, how would the video reach it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've rewritten my question and hope it is more understandable. The video viewer was `gst-launch` . Sorry for the confusing wording.

Comment: So it's the rtspsrc plugin? And you tried port-range and it didn't work?

Comment: Note that if the port range limitation is actually on the server and your client is behind NAT/PAT, there's probably nothing you can do (unless the PAT can be fine tuned as you want, which is unlikely I think) other than eliminating the limitation. (For the record, we don't know what it actually is.)

Comment: Yes, I've tried the port-range. It works for what it is supposed to do. It defines the ports for the negotiation but it does not use a port from that range for the initial request. At least on linux it is possible for gstreamer to select the source port by using _bind before connect_.

Comment: I have to clarify my last comment, it _should_ be possible. At least it's not restricted by the os. However, the documentation for the _rtspsrc_ does not mention any _bind_ command whereas the _multiudpsink_ offers _bind_.
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtspsrc.html
VS
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-multiudpsink.html